# Kansui powder to Kansui liquid (Koon Chun) conversion?

Tags: ramen

I was curious if you could help me figure out the proper conversion from Kansui powder to Kansui liquid (Koon Chun bottle).  Interestingly enough, I have a bottle of the liquid but almost any and all recipes anywhere on line are built under the consideration that one cannot find the liquid.  For instance, Ivan Ramen book recipe is 10g of Kansui powder.. what would that equate to when using the bottled liquid in a recipe?

Answer (score 1):

Google gave me this - which I don't feel in any way qualified to elucidate upon…

From [Omnivore's Cookbook - Kansui (lye water, alkaline solution, 枧水)](https://omnivorescookbook.com/kansui)

> **Homemade kansui**
>
> Making baked baking soda is easy.
>
> 1. Preheat oven to 250 degrees F (120 C). Line a baking tray with aluminium foil.
> 2. Spread baking soda on the foil and bake for 1 hour. The baking soda will lose about one third of its weight and you’ll gain a stronger
>      alkali. Do not touch it with your bare hands. It will cause irritation
>      to sensitive skin.
> 3. Transfer baked baking soda to an airtight jar to prevent it from absorbing moisture from the air.
> 4. To make an alkaline solution for mooncakes, add 1 teaspoon baked baking soda to 4 teaspoons water; stir to mix well.

I'd guess that would give you the made up strength.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to make kansui, rather he wants to use liquid in place of powdered.  So, there are two issues: the strength of the solution and how to account for the extra liquid in his noodle recipe.

Answer (score 0):

The two issues are: (a) what is the relationship between the strength of powdered kansui and it's strength when it is in solution, and (b) how to account for the extra liquid in your recipe.  I have been unable to find specific information on the strength relationship.  However, I found [this recipe](https://norecipes.com/homemade-ramen-noodle-recipe/) for ramen noodles where the author experimented with different amounts of liquid kansui. He ultimately landed on 1 tsp liquid kansui for 2 cups of flour and 1/2 cup water.  You might take your recipe and extrapolate from there, using this as a starting point.